# Getting (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-c#-sdk, access-token

I am getting the following error:

> (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Using V6 of the Facebook SDK in C#.

Below is the code that I am using, and please note that I have omitted my AppID and App Secret:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string accessToken;

    private void getAccessTokenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "OMITTED",
            client_secret = "OMITTED",
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
        accessToken = result.access_token;
    }

    private void retrieveFirstNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
        client.AccessToken = accessToken;
        dynamic result = client.Get("me");
        MessageBox.Show(result.first_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Help on OAuthException Code 2500](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9351241/need-help-on-oauthexception-code-2500)

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Figured out the problem. You're using an **app access token** to get the information about the current logged in user, which is not allowed.
You've to get the user access token to access the details about the current logged in user. The **other option** is that you can pass the user id instead of 'me' to get the information about a user who has given you the required permission.

```
dynamic result = client.Get("User_ID");
string name = result.first_name;
```

Another problem I detected in your code was you are using a wrong method to create a new `FacebookClient' with the existing access token. The correct way I suppose is to pass the accessToken in the constructor.

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient("Access_Token");
```

Here's a complete tutorial: [Working with Facebook C# SDK](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html)